# Creating a list of Sympy expressions (most of them being constant functions)

Tags: function, constants, iteration, expression, sympy

I would like to create a list of Sympy expressions. Specifically, I want to extract float-valued parameters from a predefined list that will be used as constants in the Sympy expression list.

Let me write down the piece of code that I would like to run, and point out with comments where I have a lack of understanding.

Say that parameter_list = [1, -1, 2, 3], and threshold = -1.

```
  1 Sympy_list = []
  2 for parameter in parameter_list: # parameter_list is a list of floats that serve as parameters in the Sympy expressions
  3         if parameter > threshold:
  4                 Sympy_list.append(parameter)  # create an expression that is a constant function of value "parameter"
  5         else:
  6                 Sympy_list.append(parameter * t)  # where t is the variable in the Sympy expression
```

I would now like to have the list Sympy_list = [1, -1t, 2, 3], where each element is a Sympy expression/function (not sure about the terminology here).

I am using this to create a list of Sympy-functions that define the initial past of variables in a delayed-differental equation system. The solver (JitCDDE) accepts Sympy functions, but then I cannot seem to be able to define the constant functions as found in Sympy_list.

I hope this is clear as I have very little experience with Sympy. If not, please make a comment and I'll try to communicate it better.

Comment: hi, can you please give a concrete example, with a `parameter_list` list you want to start from, a `threshold` , and run us through your algorithm and tell us what you would expect to achieve? thank you

Comment: I tried doing that now. I hope it's clearer now:)

Comment: I fail to understand what your problem is. You example code does exactly what you appear to want, provided you have some symbol `t`, for example via `from sympy.abc import t` or `from jitcdde import t`.

Comment: Oh okay, that is where my confusion was. So there is a property to the "t" object from these packages that turn expressions like [ parameter * t] into Sympy function objects?

Comment: @tutentaten: Not SymPy functions, but SymPy expressions, which is usually what you want for JiTC*DE.